# espresso - how to declare path for custom test runner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I have created a custom test runner for espresso and it looks like this:

```
    public class MyRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
  @Override
  public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
      throws Exception {
    return super.newApplication(cl, MyCustomEspressoApplication.class.getName(), context);
  }
}
```

i have placed the class inside of the androidTest folder.  Is that ok ?

Now i went to the gradle file to update the test runner and i put in this:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.mobile.myapp.base.MyRunner"
```

(is this path ok ? remember i put it in the androidTest folder).

and one of my tests classes structure looks like this:

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class AuthenticationActivityTest {
//....

@Test
   public void signupWithFacebook() {//...}
}
```

but when i run the test android studio says it cant find the test runner. here is the exact error i get:

```
   Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for:
 ComponentInfo{com.mobile.myapp.labs.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
```

Please again note my custom test runner is located here:  androidTest-->java-->com-->mobile-->myapp-->base-->MyRun‌​ner.java

UPDATE: below is the custom testrunner i am trying to use:

```
    package com.mobile.myapp.base;

import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;

import com.squareup.rx2.idler.Rx2Idler;

import io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins;



public class MyRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override public void onStart() {
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler(
                Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));
        // etc...

        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

when i check the android manifest generated i see this :

```
<instrumentation
       android:name="com.mobile.myapp.base.MyRunner"
       android:functionalTest="false"
       android:handleProfiling="false"
       android:label="Tests for com.mobile.myapp.labs"
       android:targetPackage="com.mobile.myapp.labs" />

   <application>
       <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
   </application>
```

Comment: it is. Are you that the path to the file is correct?

Comment: no i am not certain how to put the path to the file.  but the file is located here:  androidTest-->java-->com-->mobile-->myapp-->base-->MyRunner.java .     so how can i tell gradle where it is located ?

Comment: then it should be `com.mobile.myapp.base.MyRunner`

Comment: ok and do i have to reference MyRunner anywhere else in code ?

Comment: why would you need to do that ?

Comment: for example @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) should that be @RunWith(MyRunner.class)

Comment: no, it remains `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`

Answer (score 4):

finally figured this out after hours of effort.  This combination got it it work:

uninstall the current application. 
delete all testing configurations in run area by clicking on run -->edit  configurations and deleting the entire instrumentation testing configurations and then starting again. Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Please again note my custom test runner is located here:
>   androidTest-->java-->com-->mobile-->myapp-->base-->MyRun‌​ner.java

then `testInstrumentationRunner` is wrong. The path has to match the location of the file

`testInstrumentationRunner "com.mobile.myapp.base.MyRunner"`

should do it

Comment: i tried this but i still get hte following error: Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.mobile.pomelo.labs.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

Comment: could you open your test runner subclass and copy/paste the package?

Comment: and in your build.gradle defaultConfig you have `testInstrumentationRunner 'com.mobile.myapp.base.MyRunner'` ?